# Button on top of image, mouseover mouseout issue with jquery

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a series of thumbnails. When you mouse over the thumbnail, a button that is on top of the thumbnail becomes visible. It is initially invisible through the visibility property.

When I mouse over, its fine, but when I mouse over the button that is on top of the thumbnail, the button begins to flicker. It makes sense because I am mousing out of the thumbnail. My question is how can I make it so when I am over the thumbnail and the button, it doesn't act like I am mousing out of the thumb. This is what I am currently using:

```
$(".adminGalImg").hover(function()
{
    $(this).parent().find(".galImgBtn").css("visibility","visible");
},
function()
{
    $(this).parent().find(".galImgBtn").css("visibility","hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a div as a container to hold the image and button. Then when you hover over the button you are not leaving the container that is toggling the visibility.

```
<div id="#holder">
    <img class="adminGalImg" src="image source" />
    <button class="galImgButton">Button</button>
</div>


$("#holder").hover(function()
{
    $(this).parent().find(".galImgBtn").css("visibility","visible");
},
function()
{
    $(this).parent().find(".galImgBtn").css("visibility","hidden");
});
```

Comment: yep that worked. Putting it in a holder was the best way. All replies would have worked since they are pretty much the same, thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Do hover/out function on container where image and button are contained, not an image. For example:

```
<div class="container" style="background-image: url(1.png)">
    <button></button>
</div>

$(".container).hover(...);
```

This should work fine.